# Does the order of rules in userscripts make a difference?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I'm creating a userscript recently, and I've noticed a significant difference how people order the rules in userscripts? Does it really matter?

Does this:

```
// @name        Hello, name here!
// @author      Author is here!
// @description Description is here!
// @namespace   Namespace is here!
```

differs from this:

```
// @namespace   Namespace is here!
// @author      Author is here!
// @description Description is here!
// @name        Hello, name here!
```

So my question does changing the order of rules matter? Any difference? Or it's just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: These are just attributes of the script, in what way could the order matter?

Comment: @Barmar So, first, they're called "attributes" not "rules"? Second, I don't really know the way, that's why I'm asking if that's going to affect the userscript's functionality in any way.

Comment: I don't kow what they're called in general. Some of them like `@name` are just descriptive information. Others like `@exclude` affect the behavior of the script, so they're rules.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that order does not matter, unless when you have the same annotation multiple times with different values. If you need details, I guess you'll need to look into the Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey sources, or ask their maintainers specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Metadata Block** entries are processed internally by the userscript managers.

The order of the entries mostly does not matter but there are some exceptions:

- `@require` entries are processed sequentially in FireMonkey (and is expected to be the same in other managers)

As far as the userscript itself is concerned, they are JavaScript comments.

Further Information *(in alphabetical order)*:

- FireMonkey: [Metadata Block](https://erosman.github.io/support/content/help.html#Metadata-Block)
- Greasemonkey: [Metadata Block](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block)
- Tampermonkey: [Userscript Header](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#meta)
- Violentmonkey: [Metadata Block](https://violentmonkey.github.io/api/metadata-block/)

Comment: Relevant excerpts: "*Multiple `require` (injected in order)*" (in Firemonkey), "*Multiple tag instances are allowed.*" (on some tags in Tampermonkey)

Comment: @Bergi The example referred to entries that didn't matter, however, you are right. I will update my answer to reflect accordingly.

Comment: @Bergi re multiple instances, they are the same for all managers. but besides `@require`, the order of others shouldn't make any difference.